# Connect Android virtual device to Mac OS X via Parallels

Tags: android, macos, usb, parallels

I have a virtual Android OS 4.3 that is installed via Parallels 9.0. And I need to connect it to Mac OS X like external usb device.

Is there any walkthrough how to connect the virtual machine like usb device to the host OS?

Comment: You cannot connect as a USB device, but ADB supports TCP connected targets - see the ADB docs.  However, if your virtual Android device is an emulator in turn running inside a VM, you may run into a problem where the emulator does not normally listen on external network interfaces of its hosting machine. You can probably work around that with something clever such as an ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

This link should give you a indicator of what you want to do (I assume only for emulators as the previous commentator noted).

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-android-emulator-on-osx-using-parallels/

There is little point me repeating all the steps but in summary it involves -

- Ensuring Parallels & MAC can talk to each other via Shared network / allow Remote Login
- Using putty on windows to setup an SSH tunnel to your MAC using a given user